# "Array has incomplete element type" error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multiple table using 2Darrays, but I continue to get the same errors. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this problem:

My Code:

```
#include "multiplication.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
int num;
mulitpication(4);


}

void mulitpication(int num){
 /* initialize array and build*/
    int arr[num][num];
    for(int i=0; i<num;i++){
        printf("row number: %d ",i);
         for(int j=0;j<num;j++){
             printf("column number: %d", j);
            arr[i][j]= (i+1)*(j+1);
         }
    }
    }
```

Errors displayed:

```
In file included from multiplication.c:1:
./multiplication.h:4:19: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void print(int arr[][]);
                  ^
multiplication.c:5:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mulitpication' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
mulitpication(4);
^
multiplication.c:10:6: error: conflicting types for 'mulitpication'
void mulitpication(int num){
     ^
multiplication.c:5:1: note: previous implicit declaration is here
mulitpication(4);
^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times over. Instead edit the first post, in case something was missing from it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function before its definition. Make sure that

```
void mulitpication(int num);
```

is inside "multiplication.h"

Possible misspelling?

Comment: I still get the error: "./multiplication.h:4:19: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void print(int arr[][]);

Comment: Try to specify array columns size inside multiplication.h. void print(int arr[][10]). If you want to assign the size dynamically you may like to use a vector rather than an array.